# Запуск видео в iframe

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe, видео

На сайте есть слайдер, который отображает видео, приходящее из сторонник сервисов (*YouTube*, *vimeo*), загружаемое  в `iframe`. Мне нужно прокрутить слайдер на мобильном устройстве при помощи *touch*. Событие при прокрутке по области `iframe`, естественно, не возникает. Вопрос: если перекрыть `iframe` прозрачным блоком, который будет реагировать на *touch*, можно ли как-то передать событие клика внутрь `iframe`, чтобы запустить и остановить видео. Или это нереально и придется реализовывать стрелки на слайдере для прокрутки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, блок, перекрывающий видео, имеет класс `.curtain`, а само видео размещено в блоке с `id=video`.

Тогда вот этот код отправит команду на запуск видео.

```
$('.curtain').click(
    function() {
        var iframe = $('#video iframe');
        $(iframe)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
    }
);
```

Надо только иметь ввиду, что для того, чтобы YouTube API работало, ссылка на видео в `iframe` должна иметь такой вид:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/код-вашего-видео?enablejsapi=1&wmode=transparent`

Подробнее о старте/паузе видео можно почитать в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633606/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-youtube-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5).